# query one to many relationship and filter when all "many" are complete

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query that lists orders (one) and all associated purchase orders (many) for that order.  I have a couple of checkboxes "Shipped" and "Delivered" for each purchase order

What I need to filter is all orders where all the associated purchase orders have been shipped and delivered.  If there is one or more purchase orders that are not "delivered" for an order, I don't want that order to show up.  Once an order delivers complete, that order is invoiced.

I have the query setup and currently displays everything that has either shipped and not delivered as well as shipped and delivered.  Right now, the report is printed and then those where all purchase orders for the order are shipped and delivered, are invoiced.

I set query parameters to yes for both shipped and delivered, but it will include orders that have at least one purchase order that has not delivered.

Comment: You should post attempted SQL in your question.

Comment: @June7 then shall we not wait for the OP to post their attempt before feeding an answer? StevenT please provide a [minimal reproducible example to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The essential table structure and relationship is described in narrative. Posting their SQL would provide actual table and field names and a basis to work with but I expect they can translate from my generic example.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE NOT OrderID IN (
    SELECT OrderID_FK FROM PurchaseOrders WHERE Delivered = False)
```

or a "find unmatched" query

```
SELECT Orders.* FROM ORDERS LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT DISTINCT OrderID_FK FROM PurchaseOrders WHERE Delivered=False) AS POs 
ON Orders.OrderID=POs.OrderID_FK 
WHERE OrderID_FK IS NULL;
```

In either case, add whatever additional criteria needed to exclude orders that have already been invoiced.

Instead of yes/no fields for Shipped and Delivered, date/time would be more informative.

Comment: Here's the current SQL for the query:

SELECT tblAcknowledgment.OrderID, tblAcknowledgment.CustomerName, tblAcknowledgment.EstimatedShipDate, tblPurchaseOrder.PONo, tblPurchaseOrder.VendorName, tblPurchaseOrder.Delivered, tblPurchaseOrder.Shipped, tblAcknowledgment.Status
FROM tblAcknowledgment INNER JOIN tblPurchaseOrder ON tblAcknowledgment.OrderID = tblPurchaseOrder.OrderID
WHERE (((tblAcknowledgment.EstimatedShipDate)<=Now()) AND ((tblAcknowledgment.Status)="Backlog") AND ((tblPurchaseOrder.POShipName)="Choose Vendor for Fabric Orders"))
ORDER BY tblAcknowledgment.EstimatedShipDate;

Comment: You should edit your question to include that info. Did you even try adjusting for either of the examples I provided?

Comment: This is the code for a report than then lists all orders = or less than today's date and I see which ones have both shipped and delivered boxes checked for all underlying POs and then invoice them.

Comment: Sorry about that June7.  Playing cartchup and the first time for me to use this site.